# Pokémon GO - Pokémon max level & cost of stardust and candy?

Tags: pokemon-go

Does anyone have screenshots or documented proof regarding the max level of Pokémon? Is there no limit on how much you can "power up" your Pokémon?

Also, I'd like a list of the costs of "stardust" and "candy" used in each "power up".

I want to calculate how many "stardust" and "candy" I'd need to max my Pokémon.

So far, I've found [this](http://www.gamepur.com/guide/23665-pokemon-go-stardust-and-candies-cost-pokemon-level.html) and [this](http://onlinefanatic.com/pokemon-go-stardust-cost-guide/) but these two provide different data, so I'm not sure which one to believe.

Answer (score 1):

Actually they are both the same. One is basing every level(1,2,3) and the other has half level's( 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5...)

Notice one maxes out at 80 and the other at 40. This was done to match the trainer level with the Pokemon level. every trainer level you go up you can level a Pokemon up twice.

Comment: Do you have proof of that though?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the IV Rater [here](https://thesilphroad.com/research), if you set the trainer level to maximum (40), you will see that the maximum Pokemon level is also 40.0.

The cost to level up to this (from 39.5 to 40.0) is 15000 stardust and 15 candy.

For a list of candy/stardust per level up, I believe your first link is correct. The second is definitely incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Within the data of [Pokemon GO GAME_MASTER protobuf decoded](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/077d6dea82d58b8febde54ae9729b1bf), there are two power ups per level and 40 levels.  Hence, from your question, the first link shows the stardust and candy cost per power up while the second link shows stardust cost per level.  The numbering of levels or power ups is immaterial, but currently there are 80 possible power ups.